# Verb usage with always

Tags: verbs, modal-verbs

Consider the following two sentences:

1. John always play football.
2. John always plays football.

Which of the above two sentences are correct? The first sentence seems right to me since there are too many 's' in the second one. Is "*always*" acting as a modular verb here? Thanks for any help.

Comment: "Always" is an adverb, not a modal. So "always plays" is correct here. You should probably have been able to work that out from a dictionary, to be honest.

Comment: @rjpond Thanks a lot. I did not know that "always" is an adverb. I should have spent more time studying about it. Thanks again.

Comment: The number of Ss in a sentence is no guide to anything.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I agree with that. However, sometimes a sentence just doesn't feel correct when said out loud. :(

Comment: Don't rely on feelings. Rely on knowledge that comes from research and study.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I completely agree with you. However, there are just so many rules and exceptions in English grammar that I give up trying to understand it.

Comment: @InuyashaYagami Don't give up! Best of luck with your studies.

Comment: @rjpond Thanks for the encouragement. :-D

Comment: The inclusion of _always_ in the sentence makes no difference to the verb form. John is one person so _he plays_.